# What are the antonyms of well and swell?

Tags: antonyms

I know that the antonym of good is bad, but I’ve always wondered what the antonyms of well (as in a adjective: “I am well”) and swell (as in a adjective: “a swell morning today”)
because these words are used very differently, and not interchangeable, therefore, their antonyms aren’t either.

Comment: I'm doing well - I'm doing badly/poorly

Answer (score 1):

"well" vs "sick"

"swell" vs. "crappy" or "lousy".